# Visualize multiple box plot selecting differents rows of a dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot

I am developing an EDA (Estimation of Distribution Algorithm). I'm getting all measure of the Pareto Front's solutions with distint configurations.

I have a structure with all values:

```
> metrics20
# A tibble: 320 x 6
   File           Hypervolume `Modified Hypervolume` Spread Spacing  Time
   <chr>                <dbl>                  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 001-unif-0.csv       25771                 26294.   391.    30.1  16.8
 2 002-unif-0.csv       27481                 28416.   534.    41.1  16.5
 3 003-unif-0.csv       26394                 26842.   356.    29.6  16.5
 4 004-unif-0.csv       30828                 31696    418.    38.0  16.5
 5 005-unif-0.csv       28146                 28727    444.    34.2  16.6
 6 006-unif-0.csv       30176                 31006    451.    50.1  16.6
 7 007-unif-0.csv       29374                 30216    537.    35.8  16.5
 8 008-unif-0.csv       27434                 28156.   439.    31.4  16.5
 9 009-unif-0.csv       28944                 29426    471.    33.7  16.4
10 010-unif-0.csv       28339                 29302.   576.    44.3  16.4
```

I want to visualize the values by this way. I take for example the Hipervolume column, I split data by File column value: `-unif-, -sat-, -eff-` and `-prod-` distribution and show values with `-0.csv,-0.25.csv,-0.5.csv` and `-0.75.csv` in `x` axis for the same distribution.

[image]

Reproducible example:

```
library(readr)
metrics20 <- read_csv("./metrics20.csv")
```

Data: [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/108DdP_ShkDJeFvdMFubiVxu2FKqXRjQL/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this is a step towards what you're looking for:

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

metrics20 <- read_csv("metrics20.csv")

metrics20 %>% 
  mutate(tag = factor(gsub("(^\\d+-)(\\w+)(-.*$)", "\\2", .$File), levels = c("unif", "sat", "eff", "prod")),
         level = gsub("(^\\d+-\\w+-)(.*)(\\.csv$)", "\\2", .$File)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = level, y = Hypervolume)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~tag, nrow = 1)+
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

From here there may be other things you want to tweak if you need to adjust it to be more like the example plot. You should be able to find all next steps in the help for the functions used.

[image: Boxplot]